# Parallax banner not working under IE10, fine In other browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css

So My parallax banner bug under IE10. It freeze, does not animate, and sticks on second image.

It works fine in all other browsers. I cannot see what is wrong.

this is the website: http://www.onethousandsheep.com/

the code is rather long, and replacing it all with the one provided from da-plugin without editing, I still get the same problem: here it is anyway:

html:

```
<div id="da-slider" class="da-slider">
<div class="da-slide">
  <div class="da-img"><a title=""><img src="/img/parallaxweb-design.png" alt="" width="400" height="228"></a></div>
  <h1><a title="Web Design">Web Design</a></h1>
  <div class="pxtext">
    <p>We design websites tailored to your needs, from presentation site to e-commerce.<span>Crisp, responsive and award winning design targeted for your audience.</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="da-slide">
  <div class="da-img"><a title=""><img src="/img/parallaxdesign.png" alt="" width="400" height="228"></a></div>
  <h1><a title="SEO">SEO</a></h1>
  <div class="pxtext">
    <p>Search Engine Optimisation, your Brand name, ranking at the top of any search engine.<span> We'll ensure you appear above your competition, whatever your expertise.</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="da-slide">
  <div class="da-img"><a title=""><img src="/img/parallaxbrand.png" alt="" width="400" height="228"></a></div>
  <h1><a title="Brand">Brand</a></h1>
  <div class="pxtext">
    <p>Logo, Business card, Flyer, etc. Your image is important, make it appealing.<span>An esthetic identity, that strikes an impact.</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
<nav class="da-arrows"> 
<span class="da-arrows-prev">
  <div class="arrowContainer">
    <div class="mouseclickleft">
      <div class="topSquareleft"></div>
      <div class="bottomSquareleft"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </span> 
  <span class="da-arrows-next">
  <div class="arrowContainer">
    <div class="mouseclickright">
      <div class="topSquareright"></div>
      <div class="bottomSquareright"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </span> 
  </nav>
```

css:

The css is huge, and when I try to put it here, it bugs out, best is to f12 it, unless someone can tell me how to put it here without it going weird.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by moving all the keyframes to another css file. whatever ><